# Ionic - using bower to install modules

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, bower

Recently my team has started an Ionic project. For my part, I need to use `angular-messages` and so I execute `bower install angular-messages#1.5.3` as stated in the [document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages). The module is downloaded successfully to the path stated in `.bowerrc`.

```
<myProject>
    |---<other folders>
    |---www/
        |---<other folders>
        |---lib
            |---<modules>
        |---<other files>
    |---<other files>
    |---.bowerrc
    |---bower.json
```

I expect `<myProject>/bower.json` is updated automatically once the new package is installed in my current project. Obviously, it is not the case.

Then I found that the `-S` or `--save` option can be used to write the dependencies of installed modules to `bower.json`. I run the command `bower install --save` and it returns the results as follows.

[image: bower install --save]

However, there are no changes made to `bower.json`. What is the correct way to update `bower.json`?

At first I was planning to simply commit `bower.json` to version control, so my teammates could update their projects locally by referencing the latest `bower.json`. Is this the recommended approach?

Comment: Please provide your directory structure, You may not execute the command in the same directory as `bower.json`.

Comment: @Nhan Updated the directory structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo add a dependency and save in tout bower.json you need to launch `bower install module_name --save` not just `bower install --save` because this last command check your file and install or update all module on it.

If with this command you haven't some result, post your bower config file because there are maybe some problems with your configuration.

To finish If you want have a project ready to use without dependency problem yes you need to commit bower.json and package.json. However If you have some proxy or weird stuff sometimes it's important to commit .bowerrc to.